# How to set caret position next to the value selected from dropdown menu using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to position the caret in the input field after the selected value from a dropdown menu using javascript?

Consider in the input field I have entered "selected value" now I place my cursor between selected and value like below

selected ^value

now from the dropdown, I select some value say "chocolate" so the value in the input field looks like below

selected chocolate value^

and the caret position is at the end of the input value. whereas I want it to be next to the end of string chocolate like below

selected chocolate^ value

how can I do it...could someone help me with this. thanks.

below is what I have tried.

```
class input extends React.Purecomponent {
    constructor(props){
        super(props) {
            this.input_ref=React.createRef();
            this.state = {
                input_val: '',
            }
        }
     handle_input = (e)=>{
         this.setState({input_val: e.target.value});
     }
     handle_select = (selected_value) => {
         this.setState({input_val: input_val + selected_value});
     }

     render = () => {
        return (
            <input 
                 ref = {this.input_ref}
                 on_change={this.handle_input}
            />
            <Dropdown
                on_change={this.handle_select}
                values={somearray}/>}
        )
     }
}
```

I am not pasting the code related to the Dropdown component since it just renders the menu. the selected value from dropdown will be added to input_val state.

Comment: Could you maybe provide some screenshots of your problem and how it renders now? It's quite hard to figure out what the actual problem is. And when you say caret, do you mean the cursor? Or is it a caret icon?

Comment: yes the cursor position

Comment: say the caret position is 2 so i used this.input_ref.current.setSelectionRange(2,2) and it doesnt work. the cursor position is always at the end of the string

Comment: That's a bit tough to do. From what I know, the options you have for changing the cursor position in an input field changes depending on what browser you're on. You might be able to do it with `setSelectionRange` as you mentioned, but I'm not quite sure how that works, unfortunately.